# За что закрыли вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Почему [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109544/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-golang-%D0%B8%D0%B7-python) был закрыт? Что в нём непонятного?

Comment: Два раза прочёл, и не понял, в чём у вас там проблема.

Comment: Вы же сами написали в комментариях: _"нельзя в C импортнуть гошные структуры"_. Но по какой-то причине отказываетесь принимать ответ, который сами же дали... Вы ищете то, не знаю что. В этом и заключается проблема вопроса.

Comment: Не понятно, как можно Вам помочь. Написать для Вас невероятную либу/линкер?) _"Good guy nailer. Sees that a friend is troubled with a code. Writes a library himself."_ А что, [как вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979864/11558617/).

Comment: Да нет. Я хочу узнать: есть ли обходные пути для этого? Вообщем, ладно, конкретизирую вопрос. Тогда, вероятно, переоткроют

Comment: @0xdb Я переформулировал вопрос. Каким образом его поставить в очередь на переоткрытие?

Comment: @hedgehogues, не знаем. Если модераторы посмотрят, значит, возможно, откроют, но не факт